# Deserialize en Java

Tags: java, serialización

En mi programa tengo un objeto Maestro, Alumno y un objeto Materia, el cuál contiene un ArrayList de maestros y alumnos.

¿Como puedo serializar un ArrayList de materias?

Ya lo intenté de la misma forma que logré serializar un ArrayList de numeros enteros, el problema viene cuando es un ArrayList de un objeto que a su vez tiene objetos adentro y lanza un InvalidClassException

Saludos

Objeto alumno:

```
package intendo2;

import java.io.Serializable;
public class Alumno extends Persona implements Serializable  {
int edad;
int calificacion;

public Alumno(int id, String nombre, String apellidoPaterno, String apellidoMaterno, String correo, int edad, int calificacion){
    super(id, nombre, apellidoPaterno, apellidoMaterno, correo);
    this.edad = edad;
    this.calificacion = calificacion;
}

public Alumno(){
    super(69420, "Andres", "Abimeri", "Romero", "andres.abimeri@gmail.com" );
    this.edad = 20;
    this.calificacion = 69;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Alumno{" + "edad=" + edad + ", calificacion=" + calificacion + '}';
}
```

}

Objeto Maestro:

```
package intendo2;

import java.io.Serializable;


public class Profesor extends Persona implements Serializable{
String titulo;




public Profesor (int id, String nombre, String apellidoPaterno, String apellidoMaterno, String correo, String titulo){
    super(id, nombre, apellidoPaterno, apellidoMaterno, correo);
    this.titulo = titulo;
}


public Profesor(){
    super(69420, "Andres", "Abimeri", "Romero", "andres.abimeri@gmail.com" );
    this.titulo = "Ing. en Informática";
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Profesor{" + "titulo=" + titulo + '}';
}
```

}

Objeto materia:

```
package intendo2;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Materia implements Serializable {
int id;
String nombre;

ArrayList<Alumno>  alumnos = new ArrayList<Alumno>();
ArrayList<Profesor>  profesores = new ArrayList<Profesor>();


public Materia(int id, String nombre){
    this.id = id;
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public Materia(){
    this.id = 55555;
    this.nombre = "Materia Generica";
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Materia{" + "id=" + id + ", nombre=" + nombre + ", alumnos=" + alumnos + ", profesores=" + profesores + '}';
}
```

}

En mi main tengo:

```
static ArrayList<Materia> materias = new ArrayList<>();
```

Escribo este parrafo porque stackoverflow no me deja publicarlo porque es mucho código y quiere que agregue mas detalles pero ya no se que agregar así que solo estoy escribiendo

Answer (score 0):

java.util.ArrayList implementa Serializable por lo que no requieres hacer algo extra. El requisito sería que los objetos dentro del ArrayList también implementen Serializable y todo se debe hacer automático.

El problema que puede estar pasando es como tienes definidas las variables tipo ArrayList en la clase Materia:

```
public class Materia implements Serializable {
 int id;
 String nombre;

 // ArrayList<Alumno>   alumnos = new ArrayList<Alumno>();
 // ArrayList<Profesor> profesores = new ArrayList<Profesor>();

//Intenta inicializarlas en algún constructor, pero no en la definición. O sea:


 ArrayList<Alumno> alumnos;
 ArrayList<Profesor> profesores;

 //etc..
```

Dado que ArrayList es Serializable la clase Materia debe poderse serializar y deserializar completa, así como sus ArrayLists